# Looking to resolve Assertion error expected 201 actual 417

Tags: spring-boot, mockito

Hi I am using mockito to test my controller and the following is my code

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = PersonController.class)
public class PersonControllerTests {


    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @MockBean
    private PersonService personService;

    private PersonController personController;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        personController = new PersonController();
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(personController).build();
    }



    @Test
    public void testCSVController() throws Exception {

        Person person = new Person(1L, "Raghunandan", "Palakodety", "07.11.1987");


        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.
                post("http://localhost:8080/person/create").
                contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
                accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
                content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(person))).
                andExpect(status().isCreated()).
                andExpect(status().isOk());

    }


}
```

When I run the test I get the following assertion error

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status 
Expected :201
Actual   :417
```

Can anyone give me some pointers where I am going wrong ?

EDIT: (Adding Controller: class PersonController)

```
@RestController
public class PersonController {

    private static final String SAVE_SUCCESSFUL = "Succesfully Saved";

    @Autowired
    private PersonService personService;

    @GetMapping("/person")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getPersons() {
        try {
            List<Person> persons = personService.findAll();

            if (persons.isEmpty()) {
                return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
            }

            return new ResponseEntity<Object>(persons, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }

    @PostMapping("/person/create")
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseMessage> create(@RequestBody Person person) {
        String message = "";
        try{
            personService.save(person);
            message = SAVE_SUCCESSFUL;
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(new ResponseMessage(message));
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            message =  COULD_NOT_UPLOAD  + "!" + e.getMessage();
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED).body(new ResponseMessage(message));
        }
    }
....
```

The end points are added in the above source code. Kindly let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: Can you show us your controller?

Comment: Added the controller class

Comment: The HTTP 417 error is what you return from your catch(). Seems like there where some exception thrown inside the ```try``` block. Do you see any error message in your logs? If you cannot find it, you could add a breakpoint to one of the line in the catch() and you could see what the actual problem is.

Comment: Hibernate: insert into person (id, dob, first_name, last_name) values (null, ?, ?, ?)
This is the message in the debug panel, and it seems working fine. But the test fails

Comment: Well, if this is the message from the exception, something is definitely wrong within the service. It's already strange that anything is being executed at all since the ```personService``` is supposed to be a ```MockBean```.

Answer (score 0):

You overwrite the services from WebMvcContext.
In particular, you overwrite a well-constructed Controller with improperly initialized one.

Remove your entire setup method:

```java
@Before
public void setUp(){
    objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    personController = new PersonController();
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(personController).build();
}
```

- `ObjectMapper` - you have it autowired
- `MockMvc` - you have it autowired, it is added by WebMvcTest
- `PersonController` - you need to interact with the controller via mockMvc, you dont need it in your test (the instance is constructed by Spring)

Why your test failed:

- you overwrote the objects mentioned above
- you did not construct the controller correctly: field `personService` is not initialized. (Hint: use constructor injection, and you will easily spot this problem)
- on interaction with `personService` you get a NPE.